# Adjusting Mysql-auth.conf filter for fail2ban gives me Python Exceptions

Tags: python, regex, filter, mysql-8.0, fail2ban

the log line TO JAIL in /etc/mysql/error.log

```
2022-06-23T16:19:10.452205Z 233 [Note] [MY-010926] [Server] Access denied for user 'webadmin'@'93.223.131.127' (using password: YES)
```

the regex

```
(?:(?:\d{6}|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[ T]\s?\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).?(?:\d+[A-Z]) ?(?:\d+ ) ?\[\w+\] (?:\[[^\]]+\] )*Access denied for user '[^']+'@'0.0.0.0' (to database '[^']*'|\(using password: (YES|NO)\))*\s*$
```

adjusted in [www.regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) and confirmed working.

match output

```
0-132   2022-06-23T16:19:10.452205Z 233 [Note] [MY-010926] [Server] Access denied for user 'webadmin'@'93.22...
111-132 (using password: YES)
128-131 YES
```

tried in filter.d/mysqld-auth.conf

```
#before = common.conf
failregex = ^%(?:(?:\d{6}|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[ T]\s?\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).?(?:\d+[A-Z]) ?(?:\d+ ) ?\[\w+\] (?:\[[^\]]+\] )*Access denied for user '[^'...etc...
```

testing with fail2ban-regex gives me

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : mysqld-auth, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/fail2ban-regex", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('fail2ban==0.9.4', 'fail2ban-regex')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 667, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1463, in run_script
    exec(code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fail2ban-0.9.4-py3.8.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/fail2ban-regex", line 34, in <module>
    exec_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fail2ban-0.9.4-py3.8.egg/fail2ban/client/fail2banregex.py", line 596, in exec_command_line
    if not fail2banRegex.start(opts, args):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fail2ban-0.9.4-py3.8.egg/fail2ban/client/fail2banregex.py", line 496, in start
    if not self.readRegex(cmd_regex, 'fail'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fail2ban-0.9.4-py3.8.egg/fail2ban/client/fail2banregex.py", line 288, in readRegex
    reader.getOptions(None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fail2ban-0.9.4-py3.8.egg/fail2ban/client/configreader.py", line 283, in getOptions
    self._opts = ConfigReader.getOptions(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fail2ban-0.9.4-py3.8.egg/fail2ban/client/configreader.py", line 137, in getOptions
    return self._cfg.getOptions(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fail2ban-0.9.4-py3.8.egg/fail2ban/client/configreader.py", line 220, in getOptions
    v = self.get(sec, option[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 799, in get
    return self._interpolation.before_get(self, section, option, value,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 395, in before_get
    self._interpolate_some(parser, option, L, value, section, defaults, 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fail2ban-0.9.4-py3.8.egg/fail2ban/client/configparserinc.py", line 58, in _interpolate_some
    return super(BasicInterpolationWithName, self)._interpolate_some(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 427, in _interpolate_some
    raise InterpolationSyntaxError(option, section,
configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: bad interpolation variable reference "%(?:(?:\\d{6}|\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})[ T]\\s?\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}).?(?:\\d+[A-Z]) ?(?:\\d+ ) ?\\[\\w+\\] (?:\\[[^\\]]+\\] )*Access denied for user '[^']+'@'<HOST>' (to database '[^']*'|\\(using password: (YES|NO)\\))*\\s*$"
```

tried also in /filter/mysqld-auth.conf

```
before = common.conf
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s(?:etc...
```

leading to
Running tests
=============

```
Use   failregex filter file : mysqld-auth, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /var/log/mysql/sample.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [0] ^<lt_<logtype>/__prefix_line>(?:(?:\d{6}|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[ T]\s?\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).?(?:\d+[A-Z]) ?(?:\d+ ) ?\[\w+\] (?:\[[^\]]+\] )*Access denied for user '[^']+'@'<HOST>' (to database '[^']*'|\(using password: (YES|NO)\))*\s*$
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1] Year-Month-Day[T ]24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?:Zone offset)?
|  [0] (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
|  [0] (?:DAY )?MON Day Year 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?
|  [0] Year(?P<_sep>[-/.])Month(?P=_sep)Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:,Microseconds)?
|  [0] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])Month(?P=_sep)(?:Year|Year2) 24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)Year[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
|  [0] Month/Day/Year:24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Month-Day-Year 24hour:Minute:Second\.Microseconds
|  [0] TAI64N
|  [0] Epoch
|  [0] ^24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] ^<Month/Day/Year2@24hour:Minute:Second>
|  [0] ^Year2MonthDay  ?24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] MON Day, Year 12hour:Minute:Second AMPM
|  [0] ^MON-Day-Year2 24hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 1 missed
[processed in 0.00 sec]
```

**what is the right way of writing this filter with fail2ban? Is #before important? how does ^%(__prefix_line)s impact? Are my tries hoax and lead python to except or is my python not properly installed?**

Using Ubuntu 20.04
THANKS!!!

Comment: In fail2ban.log i get a "winning templete" with 128 hits everytime i fail to login. So its kinda working and kinda not!? Confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of problems with your attempt:

1. Your first regex begins with `%(` string interpolation notation but it doesn't use any variable and it doesn't end like it should, so you get Python error `bad interpolation variable reference`. Python's correct string interpolation operator is `%(...)s`.
2. You need to replace the `0.0.0.0` part with either `<ADDR>` or `<HOST>` tag (first one matches IP addresses, latter one IP + host names). As it is now, it can only match 0.0.0.0 (and it won't even work with fail2ban which will throw you `ERROR: No failure-id group`).
3. Remove the part that tries to match the date pattern from the failregex. Fail2ban first cuts out the date pattern from each input log line and **then** it applies the failregex.

So, this will match what you want:

> `^\s*(?:\d+ ) ?\[\w+\] (?:\[[^\]]+\] )*Access denied for user '[^']+'@'<HOST>' (to database '[^']*'|\(using password: (YES|NO)\))*\s*$`

`%(__prefix_line)s` is used to match common line prefixes and you can see its regex in */etc/fail2ban/filter.d/common.conf*. It's optional, in your specific use case you can omit this. Otherwise you could use:

> `^%(__prefix_line)s(?:\d+ ) ?\[\w+\] (?:\[[^\]]+\] )*Access denied for user '[^']+'@'<HOST>' (to database '[^']*'|\(using password: (YES|NO)\))*\s*$`

Comment: I really have to read things 10 times again to acknowledge why things work this way, but this works! I AM BANNED! JAY!!! the <host> was only set to 0.0.0.0 so a outside regex checker can debug it, cause it doesnt know system variables. But why are those scripts not working right after installation? i get that file with install, and its for mysql. why does fail2ban ship with things that never work?

Comment: fail2ban's stock filters are evolving through time, perhaps you're using an older version of the software. I just tested the log line you provided in your post with latest fail2ban and it works out of the box for me (without changing the filter)

Comment: installed with "apt-get install fail2ban", Version: Fail2Ban v0.9.4 reads log file that contains password failure report
and bans the corresponding IP addresses using firewall rules.

Comment: same goes for SSHD filter. It is same as in Github->Fail2Ban->filters.d->sshd.conf, but gives a fail2ban.server.failregex.RegexException: No 'host' group in '<cmnfailre-failed-pub-<publickey>>'(last line)

Comment: im feeling like having a problem with my whole setup of Ubuntu/Python. Documentation says use 1d 8h etc for timing, fail2ban says "invalid value 1d, setting standard value 84000... :-/